# Return records where children are under parents

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am retriving model like this `$people = Person::with('children')->get();` and this returns me `dd($people);`

```
Collection {#322 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Person {#311 ▶}
      #relations: array:1 [▼
         "children" => Collection {#320 ▼
           #items: array:2 [▼
              0 => Child {#323 ▶}
              1 => Child {#324 ▶}
    1 => Person {#312 ▶}
    2 => Person {#313 ▶}
        #relations: array:1 [▼
         "children" => Collection {#320 ▼
           #items: array:2 [▼
              0 => Child {#323 ▶}
    3 => Person {#314 ▶}
```

But now i am trying to export this to excel ( [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) with view ) but i needed to be like this (children under their parent), for example:

```
Collection {#322 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => Person {#311 ▶} // Parent 1
    1 => Child {#312 ▶} // Child of parent 1
    2 => Child {#313 ▶} // Child of parent 1
    3 => Person {#314 ▶} // Parent 2 - Single (no relation)
    4 => Person {#315 ▶} // Parent 3 
    5 => Child {#316 ▶} // Child of parent 3
    6 => Person {#314 ▶} // Parent 4 - Single (no relation)
```

Im not sure on how to do this (Eloquent or Query Builder) ?

Comment: You could make an excel file on-demand and iterate through each Person, making each children its own row in the excel document.

Comment: @Adherence i am using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel and already made import, so i need to use view (blade) to make the sheet. But will try something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try but something like this would work I guess:

```
$c = collect([]);

foreach($people as $person)
{
    $children = $person->children;
    $c->add($person);        
    if(count($children) > 0)
    {
        foreach($children as $child)
        {
            $c->add($child);
        } 
    }
}

dd($c);
```

Comment: Good thinking. Didn't even occur to me i could do this way, thank you